# Fiddler does not allow remote computers to connect

Tags: fiddler

I have a PC running a web server on port 81 and Fiddler (4.6; Windows 7) listening on port 82. I have enabled "Allow remote computers to connect".

From an iPad in the same network I am able to access the web server but not Fiddler. If I switch the ports around and run Fiddler on 81 then I still cannot access fiddler (although I accessed port 81 previously) and now can only access the web server on port 82.

Basically Fiddler seems to not answer remote clients. Firewall is off but it's obviously not a firewall issue: the iPad can access the web server on both ports.

What could be the issue?